# Multi-touch on two CCButton not detected with Cocos2d-iphone v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am detecting when the user is holding pressed some CCButtons on the update function. I get this information by checking its **tracking** or **touchInside** attributes (both work fine).

However, those tests only work if the user press one CCButton at a time, meaning it doesn't detect the second touch (multi-touch not working).

I already setMultitouchEnabled: True on every button, the parent node and with

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

I am running the Cocos2d-iphone v3 RC1, am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, I only have to execute on the scene:

```
[self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

and

```
btn.exclusiveTouch = NO;
```

EDIT:
Another good thing to do to avoid some bugs is:

```
btn.claimsUserInteraction = NO;
```